# Xcode - View Screen size

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I am in the process of learning iOS development with XCode.  I created a project to implement some of the things I've been learning and to begin learning how to manage image sizes and placement on different sized screens i.e. iPhone 8, iPhone 8+, iPad, etc.  I am currently using XCode 10 Beta and I noticed that the View size on the main storyboard is half the actual screen size of any device I select to to View As:.  For instance if I select View As: iPhone 8 the screen size is 375x667 instead of being 750x1334 like the actual device.  I discovered this because I created a square image of 100x100px and thought I would be able to line up 7 across the screen.  To my surprise the images took up twice as much screen as I had calculated.

Can anyone let me know why the screen Views in XCode are half that of actual screen size?

Do I just always assume to make my graphics half the size I would actually want them?

Edit: Here's a screenshot of what I am referring to in XCode
[image]

When I click on the empty view in the the XCode storyboard pane this is this resolution it displays for the view.  Also, when I export my graphics from Illustrator the are exported with the @1x, @2x, and @3x variants.  However, when I place an image in the view that is 100x100px it takes up about 1/3 of the screen instead of 1/7 of the screen as I would expect on a iPhone 8 which has a resolution of 750x1334.

Edit #2: So after playing around more with XCode I do see that the resolution for the views are in Points not pixels however, in this screenshot for a iPhone 8+ View:
[image]

I would assume with a screen resolution of 1080x1920 @3x the Point resolution would be 360x640 for an iPhone 8+ not 414x736.

Comment: "Do I just always assume to make my graphics half the size I would actually want them?" No. Some screens are single resolution, some are double, some are triple. You should not care. Distinguish pixels from points, and learn about single, double, and triple resolution images in the asset catalog (or using special naming conventions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with the difference between points and pixels. On the original iPhone when it was release it was 1 point per pixel but as resolution got better it became 2x pixels per point (4 pixels). Now the resolution is 3x pixels per point on some of the newer devices (9 pixels).

https://www.google.com/amp/s/blog.fluidui.com/designing-for-mobile-101-pixels-points-and-resolutions/amp/

Comment: Technically 2x2 pixels per point (@2x device) and 3x3 pixels per point (@3x device) so an iPhone 7 will render each point with 4 pixels and an iPhone X will render each point with 9 pixels.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I have actually read that one.  I have read several sites that explain the difference between pixels and points.  When I export my graphics from Illustrator it creates 1x, 2x, and 3x variants of the image and I did place them in the assets.xcassests folder.  What puzzles me about XCode is that when setting X/Y coordinates or width/height of UIViews an the view the settings are in pixels.  Thus I assume if my graphic is 100x100px I would make my UIView 100x100px but like I said I was surprised when the graphic was almost 1/3 of the width.

Comment: Ahhhh after some playing around I see that the image in my edit is in Points not pixels .. @AlexanderClaussen I guess if I wanted the same layout on an iPad as on an iPhone I would need to control my UIView size through code?  Would I need to create different sized images for iPads vs. iPhones?  I am going to add a second image in another edit that is confusing me for the screen size for a iPhone 8+.